# What this PHP code does?

Tags: php

I read [What's the most dangerous/worst PHP script you've ever seen?](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-most-dangerous-worst-PHP-script-youve-ever-seen) on quora.

It had following code as answer with a upvote.

```
<?php
`:(){ :|: & };:`;
```

Even I have worked with PHP more than 3 years I have no idea what this code does and I am little bit scare to run on it localhost too because I don't know what it do.

What is that code?

Comment: Nothing:- https://eval.in/876236

Comment: It is bash script, not PHP. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-the-command-make-my-system-lag-so-badly-i-had-to-reboot

Comment: Here is what it really does [WiKi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)

Answer (score 1):

This question was previously asked and answered on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

In [his answer there](https://askubuntu.com/a/159494), [SuperMatt](https://askubuntu.com/users/63877/supermatt) writes:

> This is called a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).
>
> `:()` means you are defining a function called `:`
>
> `{:|: &}` means run the function `:` and send its output to the `:`
>   function again and run that in the background.
>
> The `;` is a command separator, like `&&`.
>
> `:` runs the function the first time.
>
> Essentially you are creating a function that calls itself twice every
>   call and doesn't have any way to terminate itself. It will keep
>   doubling up until you run out of system resources.
>
> Running in Virtualbox was quite sensible really otherwise you would
>   have had to restart your pc.

Comment: rene's efforts in adding attribution saved this answer from being deleted. In the future, if you're going to borrow someone else's work, you need to [properly reference it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), which means using their name, linking to their answer, and properly formatting all copied content as a quotation. We are very strict about this policy, so please keep this in mind for the future.